# Amature javascript referring to a text file

Tags: javascript, html, text, youtube, embed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     //GET DATA FROM URL ...index.html?PageTitle,YOUTUBE_ID
     var DATA = window.location.search.replace( "?", "" );
     //STORE IN ARRAY FOR EASY ACCESS AND EXPANDABILITY
     DATA = DATA.split(",");
     //LOAD THE PAGE TITLE
     document.title = DATA[0]
     //UPDATE THE IFRAME SRC AFTER THE DOCUMENT LOADS
     window.onload=function()
     {
     var YouTube = document.getElementById('YouTube'); 
     YouTube.src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+DATA[1]
     };
     </script> 

........<div class='content'>
        <iframe id="YouTube" width="853" height="480"
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
        </div>
```

I've got this code above, which allows me to change my websites embedded video depending on what the user inputs in the url. However I want the url to change to a number yet still embed a different video depending on the url so:

1: jidw82jIG8J    2: ksl9UH65Hn8    3: KNB7gvVsS9B

the url of the site would be www.mysite.com/1 and the embedded video would be jidw82jIG8J
if that makes sense, I have no idea how to go about this, this site will have an estimated 3000 videos.

Comment: Where do you plan to store the mapping between the number and the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's going to be an automatic way to get the data in there and frankly, I'm not really sure it's a great idea.

That being said you are probably going to have to create some sort of associative array.

```
var lookup = {
    1: "jidw82jIG8J",
    2: "ksl9UH65Hn8",
    3: "KNB7gvVsS9B"
};
```

Then when you have parsed the URL you can do something like `lookup[1]`;

Comment: You could also just use a regular indexed array, if all of the numbers are sequential.

Comment: True, but this seems a bit more readable, especially if he is going to have non-consecutive items.

Comment: Would your code be a good solution considering the thousands of entries I will be having?

Comment: The lookup would be very efficient, but it's going to take a lot of hand coding to get all the data in there.  Can I ask why you don't just leave the youtube reference in the URL?  There's nothing wrong with something like this `http://yoursite.com?yt=jidw82jIG8J` and it would make your page a lot more flexible and maintainable.

Comment: because I want to generate a random link, so if I make each of my video id's a unique identifier, I can generate a random number between 1 to n and make a random link

Comment: Yeah, this should work for that.  As Mark Bessey said, you don't have to use an associative array, a regularly indexed array would also work.  I would still use an associative array (like in my example) just to make it more readable.